# how to create rest api using redmine with nodejs?

Tags: node.js, redmine, redmine-api

is there any idea how can i create rest api using Redmine and nodejs.
i used [node-redmine](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-redmine) but i don't know how to create rest api.
i also google but there is no any way because i don't have knowledge about redmine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redmine already comes with Rest API.

To use API,
You need to go in Redmine to **Administration | Settings | API** and tick Enable rest services and JSONP support, then find your API key under **My account**, and use it as provided in example document from node-redmine library

```
var Redmine = require('node-redmine');


var hostname = process.env.REDMINE_HOST || 'redmine.zanran.me';
var config = {
  apiKey: process.env.REDMINE_APIKEY || 'bed1ba0544b681e530c2447341607f423c9c8781'
};

var redmine = new Redmine(hostname, config);

/**
 * Dump issue
 */
var dump_issue = function(issue) {
  console.log('Dumping issue:');
  for (var item in issue) {
    console.log('  ' + item + ': ' + JSON.stringify(issue[item]));
  }
};
```

To consume it's REST API use instructions and endpoints given here:  http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_api

To create new issue:

```
/*
 * create issue
 */
var issue = {
  "issue": {
    "project_id": 1,
    "subject": 'Redmine REST API by Node.js',
    "assigned_to_id": 5,
    "notes": "automative update redmine notes by node js",
    "priority_id": 4
  }
};

redmine.create_issue(issue, function(err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;

  console.log(data);
});
```

If you however still insist to create your own API, then I recommend you connect with nodejs directly to Redmine's database and build your own API, so you don't build proxy for Redmine's API.

Comment: yes you are right but what is my question is i want to crate api using nodejs and Redmine but i don't know how.
Redmine is provide it's own api than how can i call it using node js

Comment: You need to go in Redmine to Administration | Settings | API

Comment: there is 1)Enable REST web service and 2) Enable JSONP support
both are tick

Comment: if i want to create end point like /checkout 
than how should i with redmine ?

Comment: You need to create plugin for Redmine which will provide checkout API endpoint.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160191/discussion-between-kumbhanibhavesh-and-aleksandar-pavic).